# Gmail app - cancel notification but see number of unread

Tags: notifications, gmail, launcherpro

I have two problems with the Gmail app:

1. I'm using LauncherPro and have the Gmail app icon in the down task-bar, but I don't see the unread mail count. How can I make the unread number appear there?
2. I've found out that the fact that every incoming new mail appears in my notification screen makes me lose concentration with what I'm doing and answer without thinking properly.

How can I stop the notifications about new mail?

Answer (score 2):

For #1, it appears that Google changed the API for the Gmail app, and [Frederico has disabled that functionality](http://www.launcherpro.com/2011/07/09/upcoming-changes-to-gmail-app/) as a result.

For #2, go to the Settings in the Gmail app and select the account you're using, then uncheck "Email notifications".